# Configure a java servlet with mobilefirst application (Within war file)

Tags: servlets, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

I am working on mobilefirst 7.1 project and deployed project on websphere application server - Network Deployment.

In mobilefirst project we running a java class as servlet and I have configured that class file in to **web.xml** of IBM_Worklight_project_runtime project war file.

```
<!-- Custom Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Myservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mobile.services.Myservice</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Myservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myservice.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I know that when I have change war file, I have to configure it again.

But When I am trying to access it like

```
http://host:port/{{context_root}}/myservice.do
```

I am getting this error :
Browser --> Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found

Server Logs -->

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper doFilter SRVE8109W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter analyticsFilter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /myservice.do
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
```

As error indicates, servlet is not configured properly. I don't know if any other configurations are required.

*Same servlet is working with worklight 6.1 war file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is "not found". It means that the server reads the configuration and looks for the file where the configuration specifies it to be at, but it's not there.

```
<url-pattern>/myservice.do</url-pattern>
```

1. Provide the full log
2. Double-check the existence of the file in the specified location